# Why sometimes my python path from venv doesn't work?

Tags: python, django, python-venv

When I try to run `sudo python setup.py install` having my venv activated, I get some Django and python version mismatch error, but when I use python path which is there in venv by copying its actual path and running the same command above just by replacing python path, it do works, so I am unable to understand which it worked when I kept actual path int it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you're running a sudo command it's using system python version under root user. Try running python setup.py install without sudo within the activated venv.